# Get data from Azure Synpase to Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to load the data (tabular data in tables, in a schema named 'x' from a spark pool in Azure Synapse. I can't seem to find how to do that. Until now i have only linked synapse and my pool to the ML studio. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lake Database contents are stored as Parquet files and exposed via your [Serverless SQL endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview) as [External Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=native), so you can technically just query them via the endpoint. This is true for any tool or service that can connect to SQL, like Power BI, SSMS, Azure Machine Learning, etc.

**WARNING, HERE THERE BE DRAGONS:** Due to the manner in which the serverless engine allocates memory for text queries, using this approach may result in significant performance issues, *up to and including service interruption*. Speaking from personal experience, this approach is NOT recommended. I recommend that you limit use of the Lake Database for Spark workloads or very limited investigation in the SQL pool. Fortunately there are a couple ways to sidestep these problems.

**Approach 1:** Read directly from your Lake Database's storage location. This will be in your workspace's root container (declared at creation time) under the following path structure:

*synapse/workspaces/{workspacename}/warehouse/{databasename}.db/{tablename}/*

These are just Parquet files, so there are no special rules about accessing them directly.

**Approach 2:** You can also create Views over your Lake Database (External Table) in a serverless database and [use the WITH clause to explicitly assign properly sized schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=native). Similarly, you can ignore the External Table altogether and use OPENROWSET over the same storage mentioned above. I recommend this approach if you need to access your Lake Database via the SQL Endpoint.